# How to add dynamic value to ***text: 'Save & Next',*** in matspinnerprogress button

Tags: angular

Need to dynamically change the text in the matspinnerprogress button, below is my initial state of options

```
spinnerButtonOptions: MatProgressButtonOptions = {
            active: false,
            text: 'Save & Next',
            spinnerSize: 25,
            raised: true,
            stroked: false,
            buttonColor: 'primary',
            spinnerColor: 'accent',
            fullWidth: false,
            disabled: false,
            mode: 'indeterminate',
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this, it's an example you can use this as reference to implement your use case

HTML

```
<button (click)="changeText()">Change</button>
```

Component

```
  changeText() {
    this.spinnerButtonOptions.text = "-------New text-----";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just create very basic example for you, I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

Stackblitz Working [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-progress-buttons-demo-9tdzw5)

**HTML**

```
<spinner-button [options]="spinnerButtonOptions" (click)="save()"></spinner-button>
```

**TS**

```
spinnerButtonOptions: ButtonOpts = {
  active: false,
  text: 'Save & Next',
  spinnerSize: 25,
  raised: true,
  buttonColor: 'primary',
  spinnerColor: 'accent',
  fullWidth: false,
  disabled: false,
  mode: 'indeterminate'
}

save(): void {
  this.spinnerButtonOptions.active = true;
  this.spinnerButtonOptions.text = 'Loading Data...'
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.spinnerButtonOptions.active = false;
    this.spinnerButtonOptions.text = 'Save & Next'
  }, 3500)
}
```